# Question about Delegate not being applied when UITextFieldDelegate file is separated from ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I have placed 4 TextFields in the ViewController to compose the registration screen. When TextField is selected, I tried to adopt UITextFieldDelegate to change the borderColor, but instead of making it an extention in ViewController, I created a new class swift file and adopted the class as the delegate of the textField.

**SignUpViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var signUpTextFields: [UITextField]! {
        didSet {
            signUpTextFields.forEach { textField in
                textField.delegate = textFieldDelegate
                textField.returnKeyType = .next
            }
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    
    private weak var textFieldDelegate: TextFieldDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        signUpTextFields.first?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    @IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

**TextFieldDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    private weak var signUpViewController: SignUpViewController?
    
    init(handler: () -> SignUpViewController?) {
        self.signUpViewController = handler()
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

I want to apply signUpTextFields delegate from SignUpViewController to didSet. However, the borderColor did not change with the code above.

I think

```
init(handler: () -> SignUpViewController?) {
    self.signUpViewController = handler()
}
```

I don't seem to be able to utilize this code. How can I use this code to apply TextFieldDelegate in SignUpViewController?

Comment: Where do you assign/initialise the textFieldDelegate in your ViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you did not initialise `textFieldDelegate` to anything, so it stays nil.

Second, even if you did initialise an instance of `TextFieldDelegate`, nothing will be holding a strong reference to that object (note that the `delegate` property of `UITextField` is weak too!), and so it will be deinitialised immediately.

Your VC should hold a strong reference to `textFieldDelegate`, and remember to initialise it:

```
private lazy var textFieldDelegate = TextFieldDelegate(handler: { self })
```

It doesn't seem like you need to pass a closure here. You can just pass `self`:

```
init(_ signUpViewController: SignUpViewController) {
    self.signUpViewController = signUpViewController
}

...

private lazy var textFieldDelegate = TextFieldDelegate(self)
```